# How to let code continue running after for loop in windows bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

When I run the following [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), something happens which stops the bat file after running the `for` loop because it never outputs the `"finish ls bat file!"` and `pause` message.

test.bat:

```
for /r %cd% %%i in (*.bat) do "subtest.bat" %%i
echo "finish ls bat file!"
pause
```

subtest.bat

```
echo %~1
```

Comment: when you execute `batch-files` from a batch file, it effectively starts a new instance and `subtest.bat` is succesfully executed, the problem is, it never returns to the previous instance to execute the rest of the code, therefore we need to use `call` to execute the script in the same instance, so it is a simple change, just add `call` like  `for /r "%cd%" %%i in (*.bat) do call "subtest.bat" %%i`

Comment: thanks for your answer! another question is：is that the same between bat and batch?! I thought the bat is *.bat and batch is *.cmd, was different script!

Comment: no. a Batch file is just that, a file with batches of commands that performs a function. a Batch file can have both `.bat` of `.cmd` extension, where `.bat` is the older extension used, but still valid.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, what do you mean by "new instance"? Just to clarify: running a batch file (from another with or without `call`) does not initialise a new `cmd` instance; only execution control is passed from one batch file to the other; using `call` lets execution control to be passed back to the calling batch file...

Comment: @aschipfl yes, that is what I mean, I don't mean new instance of cmd, maybe my wording is a bit vague :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `call` like this:

```
for /r %cd% %%i in (*.bat) do call "subtest.bat" %%i
```

Here is a sample batch file (bat1.bat):

```
@echo off
for /r %cd% %%i in (*.bat) do call "subtest.bat" %%i
echo bar
pause
```

Calling `subtest.bat` with these commands:

```
echo foo
```

If you run it you get this output:

```
foo
foo
bar
Press any key to continue . . .
```

[image]

You can get more information about the `call` command by typing this on the *cmd* line:

```
call /?
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! it is work for me after testing. do you know where to learn the bat script systematically?

Comment: @HsuAmanda actually I like this tutorial for learning about windows batch file scripting: http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/